# Having error while rebuilding project in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I just updated my Android studio to the largest version and created new project but I am having this error. I even updated SDK manager but still the same error shows up.

```
Gradle tasks [clean, app:assembleDebug]
```

Execution failed for task 'app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

> Could not create service of type GeneralCompileCaches using GradleScopeCompileServices.createGeneralCompileCaches().

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to dig through the build exceptions to find that the compile failed because a lock was being held on `~/project/.gradle/4.4/javaCompile`, which was a directory so it really meant `~/project/.gradle/4.4/javaCompile/javaCompile.lock`.

Next, I ran `sudo fuser ~/project/.gradle/4.4/javaCompile/javaCompile.lock` to see what process was holding the lock.  (you might not need the `sudo` prefix)  Turned out to be `/snap/andriod-studio/53/android-studio/jre/bin/java`; might have been an abandoned compile thread.

Fully exiting and restarting Android Studio resolved this issue.  You could re-check the `fuser` command and `kill` the process if needed after exiting Android Studio.